# How to sniff other user session in Linux?

Tags: terminal, tty

Another user is connected to my machine by ssh and doing something (this is myself, running long command by ssh). How can I see in realtime, what is happening in his terminal session?

I am root on a machine.

Comment: well, strace it. you can strace all the processes from a session with `strace -p "\`pgrep -s SID\`"`.

Comment: Could you duplicate a file descriptor?

Comment: @mosvy will `strace` see SSL?

Comment: SSH != SSL. `strace` will see all the system calls done by a process (or a bunch of processes and their descendants, see the manpage) no matter if they're running inside a ssh session or whatever. Your Q is _way_ too vague; at least try to decide yourself if you want to see what you're doing in a terminal session, or you want to decrypt SSL traffic ;-)

Answer (score 1):

strace can be a heavy way to see wich system calls , if the task generate some network traffic , you can use tcpdump or tcpflow .

OTHERWISE

This is better to use `screen` or `tmux`  , and run a verbose mode of your command .

Both tools allow to detach the session . so you can logout and back later and reattach .

tmux is packaged in every linux distribution .

some tutorials can be found on the tmux wiki  https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSHPry2](https://github.com/nopernik/SSHPry2.0), first you need to list-sessions and then attach the session (something like /dev/pts/XX) you are interested as parameter of --tty. That's all.